# AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'query'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-security

I have a large database built and populated with sqlalchemy (the original - not flask-SQLAlachemy).  I would like to add flask-security to the site, and I realize it relies on flask-SQLAlachemy (instead of the original), but it is my understanding (just started trying to learn more about it) that flask-SQLAlchemy can work with the original. Entering users into the database seems to work.  When I navigate to the restricted page, it prompts me to login (as it should).  When entering the correct email address and password, I get the error `AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'query'`, and since the traceback of the error doesn't reference any of my code, I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Thinking this may have been a sqlalchemy to flask-SQLAlchemy conversion issue, I feel like I have tried everything short of creating a new database.  I haven't found anything in the flask-security or flask-SQLAlchemy documentation to help resolve this issue.  Anyone have an idea on how to resolve this?

Here is my code:

**testing.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, asc, and_, or_, func, desc
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import database_setup
from database_setup import Base, User, Role
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, UserMixin, RoleMixin, login_required

application.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'super-secret'

# Setup Flask-Security
user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(database_setup, User, Role)
security = Security(application, user_datastore)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///landtohuntalpha.db')
Base.metadata.bind = engine

DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()

@application.route('/user/add/', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def addUser():
if request.method == 'POST':
    submission = User(
        email = request.form['email'],
        password = request.form['password'],
    )
    session.add(submission)
    session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('completedUser'))
else:
    return render_template('addUser.html')

@application.route('/restricted_page/')
@login_required
def restrictedPage():
    return render_template('restricted_page.html')
```

**database_setup.py**

```
import os
import sys
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, DateTime, Boolean, Float, Date, Table
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, UserMixin, RoleMixin, login_required

Base = declarative_base()

roles_users = Table('roles_users', Base.metadata, Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('user.id')), Column('role_id', Integer, ForeignKey('role.id')))

class Role(Base, RoleMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'role'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(80), unique=True)
    description = Column(String(255))

class User(Base, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    password = Column(String(30))
    last_login_at = Column(DateTime)
    active = Column(Boolean)
    confirmed_at = Column(DateTime)
    current_login_at = Column(DateTime)
    last_login_ip = Column(String(45))
    current_login_ip = Column(String(45))
    login_count = Column(Integer)
```

**Traceback Error**

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask_security\decorators.py", line 205, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask_security\views.py", line 75, in login
    if form.validate_on_submit():
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask_wtf\form.py", line 166, in validate_on_submit
    return self.is_submitted() and self.validate()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask_security\forms.py", line 230, in validate
    self.user = _datastore.get_user(self.email.data)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask_security\datastore.py", line 191, in get_user
    rv = self.user_model.query.filter(query).first()
AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'query'
```

Comment: The problem seems to be with setting up DB connection...@Mark

Comment: @upaangsaxena I'm not sure what is wrong with the connection.  Can you elaborate? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your User class is inheriting from UserMixin (from flask-login) which doesn't have a query attribute.
can't fully explain the differences between our projects but here is my basic setup:

**init**.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, session
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import flask.ext.login as FL


# define the main app object
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
app.secret_key = 'super secret string'

login_manager = FL.LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = "/"

# create the database object
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

then in models.py (make sure you import db) make User class inherit from db.Model:

```
from flasker import db
import datetime
from flask.ext.login import UserMixin

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.Unicode(128))
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(128))
    password = db.Column(db.Unicode(1024))
    authenticated = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post')
    #-----login requirements-----
    def is_active(self):
    #all users are active
        return True 

    def get_id(self):
        # returns the user e-mail. not sure who calls this
        return self.email

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return self.authenticated

    def is_anonymous(self):
        # False as we do not support annonymity
        return False

    #constructor
    def __init__(self, name=None, email=None, password=None):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.authenticated = True
```

Comment: @Mark: This is simply suggesting non-use of the Declarative Base, which is not required, nor recommended, to fix the problem as described. You need to add `Base.query = session.query_property()` after declaring Base (and also in a session context). Then, the flask-security module will be able to access your User/etc tables using User.query... syntax.

Comment: Note that flasker is now deprecated. Use [kit](https://github.com/mtth/kit) instead.

Answer (score 7):

Add

`Base.query = db_session.query_property()`

under

`Base = declarative_base()`

in

`database_setup.py`

Ref: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/quickstart.html#id2

Answer (score 2):

You can try to modify the way you create db Models like this:

```
class User(db.Model):
    # parms
```

Generally create Models in this way will be able to let User use query method.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone gets a similar error when using Flask-Admin, check where you add the ModelViews to the `admin` object.

```
from flask_admin import Admin
admin = Admin()
```

Here:

```
                                               ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ 
admin.add_view(YourModelView(YourModelClass, db.session))
```

If it's not a `db.session` object, you would get a similar error.